# If odds is uniformly distributed, what is the distribution of probability?

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose $\pi=\frac{\theta}{1-\theta}$ where $\theta$ is between $[0,1]$.

If we set a uniform prior for $\pi$, what is the induced prior on $\theta= \frac{\pi}{1+\pi}$?

I'm stuck on this problem. Can someone help me out?

Comment: As $\theta$ ranges from $0$ to $1$, $\pi$ ranges from $0$ to $\infty$.  There is no uniform distribution on that.

Answer (score 1):

If $0\le \pi \le 1$ then $0\le\theta\le\frac 1 2 .$

\begin{align}
f_\theta(t) & = \frac d {dt} \Pr(\theta\le t) \\[8pt]
& = \frac d {dt} \Pr\left( \frac \pi {1+\pi} \le t \right) \\[8pt]
& = \frac d {dt} \Pr\left( 1 - \frac 1 {1+\pi} \le t \right) \\[8pt]
& = \frac d {dt} \Pr\left( \frac 1 {1+\pi} \ge 1-t \right) \\[8pt]
& = \frac d {dt} \Pr\left( 1+\pi \le \frac 1 {1-t} \right) \\[8pt]
& = \frac d {dt} \Pr\left( \pi \le \frac 1 {1-t} -1 \right) \\[8pt]
& = \frac d {dt} \frac 1 {1-t} \\[8pt]
& = \frac 1 {(1-t)^2} \quad \text{for } 0\le t \le \frac 1 2.
\end{align}